# Fom Sizing Grip

Tags: c#, gdi, statusbar

I like how the status bars of windows explorer/internet explorer looked like. I just want to copy their appearance but I am not successful to do so. Open up windows explorer (with View->Status Bar) and you can see a sizing grip on top of the last panel. I can't seem to be able to do it. Anybody has tried a statusbar with sizing grip on top of it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip()` can draw this thing for you, at least on my installation. Also if I add a `Controls.Add(new StatusBar());` to my Form, I'm getting the correct result. I dont know how to add it to a `StatusStrip` so not posted as answer.

Comment: if you look closely at the result of ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip() and the above image, they are different. And no, I am not going to use a StatusStrip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh well, setting the appropriate panel sizes will do the trick. :)